# Angular 2: how to force an injectable to be a singleton in the app

Tags: angular, service, singleton, injectable

I have an `@Injectable` service in my application that is added as a provider in `AppModule`. I want to make sure no one in my development team injects it in any other module. A single instance is enough and it has some complicated logic that I don't want to be run twice. Any ideas?

I know how DI works in angular 2, so answers like 'Make sure it is added as a provider only in App Module' won't help. :(

PLEASE NOTE, that I want it to produce some sort of error at build or run time if the service is provided to any other but AppModule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular maintains a single instance per provider.

Ensure you provide a service only once and DI will ensure that there is only one single instance in your application.

If you provide a service on a comonent `@Component({ ..., providers: [...]})`, then there will be as many instances as component instances.

If you provide a service only in `providers` of `AppModule` or `providers` of modules imported to `AppModule`, then there will only be a single instance for your whole application:

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [...],
  imports: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

A pitfall are lazy loaded modules. If a module is lazy loaded then providers provided there will cause another instance to be created, because lazy loaded modules have their own DI root scope.
For lazy loaded modules implement `forRoot()` and add providers that should be application-wide singletons only in `forRoot()`, but not in `providers` and import it in `AppModule`

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [...],
  imports: [LazyLoadedModuleWithSingltonProvider.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**update**

To prevent instantiation of multiple instances of a service you can use a workaround like

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private static instanceCounter = 0;
  private instanceNumber = instanceCounter++;

  constructor() {
    if(this.instanceNumber > 0) {
      throw 'MyService must be kept a singleton but more than one instance was created';
    }
  }
}
```

Another way is to move singleton services to a `CoreModule` and prevent this module being imported anywhere else than in the `AppModule`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#prevent-reimport

> Only the root AppModule should import the CoreModule. Bad things happen if a lazy loaded module imports it.

Comment: I do mention in my question that this does not answer the question. If one of the devs on my team adds this service to any other module as a provider, there will be multiple instances of the service. I want to force that it produces an error while building or at least at runtime.

Comment: You are right. I somehow forgot about that while answering :-/. I updated my answer. Angular doesn't provide anything.